# How to add a filter to existing search results

Tags: php, sql

Background:
I currently have a set up where people are dropped in page where they have BB Cards they don't own.  I want them to be able to filter out the EXISTING list to narrow it down...

How do I add a filter with PHP to that EXISTING search result so they can break it down? Here is my existing relevant code:

```
<div id="col2"><br><br><center>Your Baseball Cards<center><br><br><br>
<?php
$servername = "********";
$username = "******";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "*******";
$username1=$_SESSION['activeusername'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['activeid'];
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM useritems JOIN (users, iteminfo) on (users.id=useritems.UserID AND iteminfo.ID=useritems.ItemID) AND userid!='$userid' LIMIT 100";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='iteminfo.php?id=". $row['id']."'><div id='frame'>
<div id='splash-image' style='background: url(".$row['imagename']."); background-size:cover;'></div>
<div id='text'>
<table >
<tr>
    <td>Player:</td>
    <td>".$row["player"]."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Brand:</td>
    <td>".$row["brand"]."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Year:</td>
    <td>".$row["year"]."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price:</td>
    <td>".$row['price']."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "You Have No Baseball Cards!!!";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</div>

<div id="col3">column 3</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>

</body>
</head>
<html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input data and expected results, as well as what is currently happening? Its a bit hard at the moment to determine what your goal is.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I am really bad at this...Let me try to explain, maybe you can't point me on the right track.  Right now when people go to THIS page, they get dropped with a bunch of BBcards they DON'T OWN ( a != search)...as people register cards, browsing gets unmanageable.  I want to set up something to filter through all the cards they DON'T OWN. I don't know if I am just looking for a regular search function or if it's something special that filters existing search results

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want by filtering, but I assume you mean that the user can filter based on Player, Brand, Year, etc. If that's the case, then you can add a WHERE clause to your SQL statement.

Here is an example using filtering by player (assuming you have an  element and a form to submit.

```
$where_clause = "AND player='" . filter_var($_POST['player'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . "'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM useritems JOIN 
(users, iteminfo) ON (users.id=useritems.UserID AND iteminfo.ID=useritems.ItemID)
WHERE userid != '$userid' $where_clause LIMIT 100";
```

If you want, you can do this in a loop with multiple inputs, appending to the WHERE clause any additional filters the user entered.

Comment: Brian, thanks!  Is there a way to let the user filter through HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What field(s) do they want to filter on?

You can use a simple form:
`<form action="..." method="post">
Player: <input type="text" name="player"/><br/>
Brand: <input type="text" name="brand"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>`

Comment: I am obviously not explaining this well...Players, Brand, Yeah, Price...so right now they can just scroll and it's like a pintrest feed of baseball cards...but suppose the want an "Andre Dawson, Fleer card from 1989"...I want them to be able to filter down to go off to the side and filter using a form to see if anyone says they have one.   The difficulty I am having is once the page has delivered the search (what you see above) I don't know how to let the user filter through the search results to make it more managable

Comment: You will need to use Javascript to do that. If you don't want to have to download the whole list to display the page, you'll need to use AJAX as well to send filter requests. Sites like Pinterest use AJAX to dynamically load and filter results on the fly. The AJAX requests can talk to the PHP server, which does the actual query.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I was hoping it wouldn't be that route...so much to learn

Comment: Yeah. I'd suggest starting with just an HTML form and submitting it to PHP, and then add the AJAX/Javascript later. Then you don't have to learn everything at once.